# Run a linux Python package on Windows computer

Tags: python, linux, windows, package, anaconda

I am running **Python 2.7** on **Windows 10** in a **Conda environment**.

I can change starting set up (but not operating system) if it will enable me to install the package I need, **Atomic Simulation Environment**.

I have tried installing the correct version of this package, using pip but it managed to corrupt my entire Anaconda install - I had to reinstall from scratch.
I imagine this is because the package is only intended to run under Linux/OSX.

***1)*** Are there any workarounds for this situation -  where a Windows user needs to run a package designed for UNIX type operating systems?

***2)*** If there are, are they general or package specific?

I have searched for several hours with absolutely no success.

Comment: did you just try : `conda install -c conda-forge ase` ? or  `conda install -c jochym python-ase` ?

Comment: First command seems to have worked just testing it out now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes works great. Thanks again. I need to investigate conda-forge and find out how that was generated.

Comment: just here : https://conda-forge.org/ and also because Atomic Simulation Environment is available for windows : https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ase